# Spring Integration - Aggregation with JDBCChannelMessageStore

Tags: spring-integration, aggregation, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.x and Spring integration 5.0.x. I could successfully implement aggregation of events with custom logic of correlationStrategy and releaseStrategy, I do not need to use splitter.

```java
    
      @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow aggregateFlow() {
            return f -> f
                    .transform(transformUtils::toSvcInput)// this will transform the input event
                    .aggregate(agg -> agg.outputProcessor(group ->
                                    new ResultAggregator("TBD",group.getMessages()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(message -> (RusultService) message.getPayload())
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                            .correlationStrategy(cs -> ((RusultService)cs.getPayload()).getEvent().getApplicationNumber())
                            .releaseStrategy(group -> (group.getMessages().stream()
                                    .allMatch(e -> ((RusultService)e.getPayload()).getEvent()
                                            .getProducts().get(0).getSubProductCode().equals("500")) && group.getMessages().size()==2) ||
                                    (group.getMessages().stream()
                                            .noneMatch(e -> ((RusultService)e.getPayload()).getEvent()
                                                    .getProducts().get(0).getSubProductCode().equals("500")) && group.getMessages().size()==1))
                            .messageStore(jdbcMessageGroupStore)
                            .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(false)                       
                            .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                            .discardChannel("nullChannel")
                            .groupTimeout(600000L))
                    .channel("subsequentFlow.input");
        }
```

messageStore is a JdbcMessageStore configured with Oracle datasource.

Q1. is the above configuration is good in cluster environment, multiple instances of this code gets deployed, any other parameters to be configured?.

Q2. if I change correlationStrategy /release strategy logic and redeploy the application previous messages in message store getting stuck, not released (expired) even after timeout. any other work around for this?

Q3. if I create another aggregator with different custom logic with same message store, would there be any issues?

Q4. How do I implement the same aggregation (with custom releaseStrategy and correlationStrategy) with JdbcChannelMessageStore (is it right use case), do you have a sample project?

I'm planning implement same aggregator bean (with custom releaseStrategy and correlation logic) with annotations and make it pluggable as my different microservices have different custom aggregation logic.

I'm very much interested to know the answer for Q4, Appreciate your inputs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks correct.
2. That's a bug; I opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3334).
   You can work around it using a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` instead of using group timeout.
3. No; as long as it has a different correlation algorithm (but see my note in the issue).
4. The channel store is not designed for use here; it's an optimization for JDBC table-backed channels.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary, that helps, will do further testing with suggested changes and get back if I come across any issues.